# Spline chart does not overlap with arearange chart (Highcharts framework)

Tags: highcharts

My goal is to have an arearange chart with bolded only top "border" with additional markers just on hover. I was trying to achieve with just one arearange graph, but I think it is not possible with arearange chart (linewidth works for both bottom and top border, and I am not able to show marker at all...). I have decided to go on with additional spline chart that would exactly overlap the top border of arearange chart. I have provided the working example in here:

in jsfiddle go to check: /ZvZDZ

As you can see on the top of the chart, spline graph does not exactly over lap the arearange chart, although data is this same.

1. Is there a way to fix that, so those both graphs would overlap
2. maybe there is a way to use just arearange chart without spline chart?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use or:

- line series and arearange
- spline series and areasplinerange

Just mixes spline and arearange will provide example you can see. Unfortunately using only one  arearange series is not possible - markers are disabled.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvZDZ/2/

Code:

```
                    series: [{
                        type: 'areasplinerange',
                        name: 'areasplinerange',
                        data: areaData,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'spline',
                        data: splineData
                    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I actually went with arearange and line, I wanted more sharp edges. Thanks!